# How to form a projection matrix in OpenCV and Matlab calibration tool box?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision

The projection matrix in camera calibration is a 3x4 matrix

> P = camera matrix * [R|t]

However in the [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera), it didn't mention if the R and t are formed by the [rvec and tvec](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera), the calibration target object space to the camera space transformation, or they are formed by the camera world space orientation `rodrigues(rvec).t()` and `- rodrigues(rvec).t() * tvec'`. The wikipedia gives a more detailed [explaination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning).

> T is the position of the origin of the world coordinate system expressed in coordinates of the camera-centered coordinate system. T is often mistakenly considered the position of the camera.

But I still kind of confused, so what exactly the extrinsic parameters ? Is it the T above, or the extrinsic parameters should be the camera position and orientation in the world space, and the R and t in the projection matrix formula should not be the extrinsic parameters ?

I'd like to confirm what exactly the R and t in the projection matrix are ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically the extrinsic parameters are used to transform homogeneous world coordinates into camera coordinates. Afterwards the intrinsic parameters are used to map points in camera coordinates onto the image plane, which leads to pixel coordinates.

Wikipedia quotes `R` and `T` and they are equivalent to the `R` and `t` of your projection matrix `P`. `R` basically represents the orientation of the camera coordinate system and `t` is the origin of the world coordinate system in camera coordinates.

However, if you want to make the camera centre `C` (in world coordinates) explicit you have to rewrite your projection matrix:

```
P = K[R|-RC].
```

As you can see `t=-RC`, but actually there is no difference. Both combinations are *extrinsic parameters*.

For more details, [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/) is kind of the bible regarding this field.

I hope I answered your question. Do no hesitate to ask if something was not clear or if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Thanks! In your answer, if my R is the orientation of the camera in the world space, should the formula be P = K[R.transpose() | -R.transpose() C] ?

Comment: I am not sure if it valid to say "R **is** the orientation of the camera in the world space", better use the term _represent_.  However, the row (unit) vectors of R, if I am not mistaken, are the coordinate axis of the camera coordinate frame in world coordinates. You basically project (dot-product) your point in world coordinates on them.

Comment: the orientation of the camera in the camera space seems meaningless. But I'm still confused. So in the answer you actually meant the R in the P = K[R|-RC] is the same R of the orientation in the world space ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. However, if you ask if `R` **is** the orientation of the camera in world space I can not really say yes, it's just a orthogonal 3x3 matrix. But `R` **represents** the camera orientation in world coordinates and **is** the matrix which transforms a 3D point in world coordinates into a coordinate system which coordinate axis are aligned with the ones from the camera coordinate system (it remains the translation by `t` to really get to camera coordinates).

Comment: I just implemented P = K[R|-RC] but it is still not the projection matrix can be used in my reconstruction algorithm. still working on it.